# TypeError for pickle of array of custom objects in Python

Tags: python, pickle, kivy, stderr

I have the following method:

```
def save(self):
    vertices = self.mindmap.get_vertices()
    edges = self.mindmap.get_edges()

    output = open('mindmap.pkl', 'wb')

    pickle.dump(edges, output)
    pickle.dump(vertices, output)

    output.close()
```

When I call this method, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 72, in <module>
    MindMapApp().run()
  File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/app.py", line 792, in run
    runTouchApp()
  File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/base.py", line 481, in runTouchApp
    EventLoop.window.mainloop()
  File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 381, in mainloop
    self._mainloop()
  File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 287, in _mainloop
    EventLoop.idle()
  File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/base.py", line 324, in idle
    self.dispatch_input()
  File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/base.py", line 309, in dispatch_input
    post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
  File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/base.py", line 275, in post_dispatch_input
    wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
  File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:4537)
  File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/uix/behaviors.py", line 110, in on_touch_up
    self.dispatch('on_release')
  File "_event.pyx", line 312, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:4491)
  File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/lang.py", line 1299, in custom_callback
    exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
  File "./mindmap.kv", line 14, in <module>
    on_release: app.save()
  File "main.py", line 27, in save
    pickle.dump(vertices, output)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1370, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 615, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 71, in _reduce_ex
    state = base(self)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 0 positional arguments (1 given)
```

I do not get this error if both arrays are empty. When the above was generated `edges` was empty and `vertices` had a size of one. I really don't know how to interpret this error, and as such have no idea how to resolve it.

This is my `Vertex` class `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, pos=None, size=None):
    super(Vertex, self).__init__()

    self.pos = pos
    self.size = size

    if self.height < self.MINIMUM_HEIGHT + self.TEXT_OFFSET:
        self.height = self.MINIMUM_HEIGHT + self.TEXT_OFFSET

    if self.width < self.MINIMUM_WIDTH + self.TEXT_OFFSET:
        self.width = self.MINIMUM_WIDTH + self.TEXT_OFFSET

    self.originalSize = self.size
    self.originalWidth = self.size[0]

    self.newIdea = TextInput(
        height = self.MINIMUM_HEIGHT,
        size_hint = (None, None),
        pos_hint = {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5},

        background_active = '',
        background_normal = '',

        use_bubble = True,

        foreground_color = (.4, .4, .4, 1),
        cursor_color = (.4, .4, .4, 1))
    self.newIdea.bind(text=self.on_text)

    self.idea = Label(
        height = self.MINIMUM_HEIGHT,
        size_hint = (None, None),
        pos_hint = {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5},
        color = (.4, .4, .4,1))

    Logger.info('Vertex: created')
```

Comment: What kind of objects are found in the `vertices` list?

Comment: Mysterious question. I'd love to see a [short, self contained, runnable example](http://www.sscce.org/) that exhibits the error, if possible.

Comment: The objects in the `vertices` list are a custom class called Vertex(ScatterLayout) where ScatterLayout is a kivy object class (http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scatterlayout.html).

Comment: @kevin one would have to install the kivy framework; making it not so self-contained, or short.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case. Darn frameworks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unless he is overriding `__init__` in his `Vertex` subclass.  I'd also want to double check any members of the custom class for `__init__` methods, as well as to see for sure exactly what object is mid-pickle at the time things blow up.

Comment: @SilasRay: The object in mid-pickle is a direct child of a list object. And yes, I meant the `Vertex()` class.

Comment: @SilasRay added __init__ method for the Vertex class. How do I work out which object is mid-pickle?

Comment: Hrmz. I suspect it is actually the Kivy `EventDispatcher` object that is the cause here. The [`object.__reduce_ex__` method](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d4fd55278cec/Lib/copy_reg.py#l59) (implemented in Python in the `copy_reg` module), searches for a class with `__flags__ & 512` being `False`, which *custom classes don't have*.

Comment: You should be able to write your own reduce `__reduce__`\ `__reduce_ex__` or `__getstate__`\ `__setstate__` methods on your object to define pickling for yourself.  However, before doing that, you might just want to think about your own custom save serialization routine, instead of relying on `pickle`, since you'd be writing 40%+ of it anyway to get `pickle` working.

Comment: Related post: [Saving a kivy widget to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18693929), but giving the same advice as I did.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I saw that post, but when I tried it out I got the same error as I showed in the comments of your solution.

Comment: @noilly: yup, hence me only referencing it as related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the Kivy `EventDispatcher` object is at fault here; the [`object.__reduce_ex__` method](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d4fd55278cec/Lib/copy_reg.py#l59) searches for the first baseclass that is not a custom class (it does *not* have the `Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE` flag set), to call `__init__` on that class. *This fails* for that base class, as it's `__init__` method doesn't support passing in a single argument.

The work-around is to use the latest pickle protocol instead; it uses a different codepath:

```
pickle.dump(edges, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
pickle.dump(vertices, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

because the latest pickle protocol (2) supports new-style classes much more efficiently.

Seeing the complexity of the Kivy object hierarchy, you may need to customise the pickling process.

I'd look into implementing the [`__getnewargs__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) for example:

```
def __getnewargs__(self):
    return (self.pos, self.size)
```

would ensure that *just that data* is pickled, nothing more. On unpickling, these two values are then used to create *new* `Vertex` objects. Note that for this method to be used you *have* to use the latest protocol!

You could also implement a [`__getstate__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__); if you return a dictionary, no mirror `__setstate__` method is required, but *would* allow you to initialise some more attributes.

If neither is implemented, the contents of the instance `__dict__` is pickled instead. Make sure that everything contained *can* be pickled.

Comment: It's probably prudent to look at writing a custom save routine in any case.  Pickling is probably going to encode a lot of information that is not strictly necessary to reconstruct the saved object state, so it'd likely end up being more efficient anyway.

Comment: I updated the code with the work-around that was provided, and got this error: pickle.PicklingError:

`Can't pickle <type 'code'>: it's not found as __builtin__.code`

Comment: @noilly: the `<type 'code'>` could be coming from `self.newIdea.bind(text=self.on_text)`, or similar state. I've updated my answer with more general advice on pickling. Stick to protocol 2, implement either `__getnewargs__` or `__getstate__` / `__setstate__` and you should be in a much better position.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I finally got a chance to implement your solution, and while it did resolve my issue, I seem to have run into another one in regards to pickling a `weakref`. If you're interested it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644920/pickling-weakref-in-python