# Pickling weakref in Python

Tags: python, pickle, weak-references

I am still pretty new to Python and even newer to pickling. I have a class `Vertex(ScatterLayout)` with a [`__getnewargs__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__):

```
def __getnewargs__(self):
    return (self.pos, self.size, self.idea.text)
```

My understanding is that this will cause the pickle to pickle the object from `__getnewargs__()` rather than the object's dictionary.

The pickle is called in the following method (in a different class `MindMapApp(App)`):

```
def save(self):
    vertices = self.mindmap.get_vertices()
    edges = self.mindmap.get_edges()

    output = open('mindmap.pkl', 'wb')

    #pickle.dump(edges, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    pickle.dump(vertices, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    output.close()
```

When I call the `save()` method I get the following error:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'weakref'>: it's not found as __builtin__.weakref
```

What am I missing or not understanding? I have also tried implementing the `__getstate__()` / `__setstate__(state)` combination, with the same result.

Comment: do you mean class has __getnewargs__ and that will cause error when do pickle.dump(a), if suppose class A and a = A()? Because i try it and no error return, could you give more details about problem? like how your class defined

Comment: I think the issue is I need to knwo two things: a) how to handle weakrefs when pickling a class; b) why a weakref is being created when the items that are pickled a returned by `__getnewargs__()`.

Comment: You're not pickling the class instance (i.e. `self`), you're pickling `vertices`.  Which is, presumably, a `weakref`.

Comment: @roippi How do I resolve this? I tried pickling each instance by looping through the `vertices` list and got the same error.

Comment: I converted the list to a dictionary. Didn't help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You definitely can serialize a `weakref`, and you can serialize a `dict` and a `list`.
Basically, it matters what the objects contain.  If the `dict` or `list` contains any unpicklable items, then the pickling will fail.  If you want to pickle a `weakref`, you have to use `dill` and not `pickle`. `dill` extends `pickle` to include objects that are otherwise unpicklable with `pickle`. However, note that with `dill`, an unpickled `weakref` will deserialize as dead references.

```
>>> import dill
>>> import weakref
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()))
<WeakKeyDictionary at 4528979192>
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(weakref.WeakValueDictionary()))
<WeakValueDictionary at 4528976888>
>>> class _class:
...   def _method(self):
...     pass
... 
>>> _instance = _class()
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(weakref.ref(_instance)))
<weakref at 0x10d748940; dead>
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(weakref.ref(_class())))
<weakref at 0x10e246a48; dead>
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(weakref.proxy(_instance)))
<weakproxy at 0x10e246b50 to NoneType at 0x10d481598>
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(weakref.proxy(_class())))
<weakproxy at 0x10e246ba8 to NoneType at 0x10d481598>
```

Comment: hey using `dill` how can you store it in a ```.pkl``` file?

Comment: you mean like with `dill.dump(weakref, open('file.pkl', 'wb'))`?

Comment: oh cool, thanks dude

Comment: hey @Mike McKerns it still doesn't work i get this error ```TypeError: cannot pickle 'tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session.TF_Operation' object```

Comment: Test cases I tried seem to work.  You should submit a GitHub issue for dill.  The comments on a SO post is not a good place to debug issues.

Comment: Sorry but I have to -1 for saying "you can pickle a weakref" unless someone can explain to me why using `dill` should be called "pickling", or why "pickling" should not specifically mean using `pickle`. Because to me that seems seriously misleading - not just some pedantic terminology nit that doesn't matter, but something liable to cause real problems from confusion/conflation/misconception.

Comment: In the python community "to pickle" and "to serialize" are pretty synonymous. Note also that "pickle" is commonly used as a verb.  The primary mechanism for serializing an object in python is pickling (marshaling is much more rare). By saying "pickling" people can understand that `dill` extends the STL `pickle`... and thus `dill` is using the `pickle` protocol and `pickle` itself to serialize the weakref.  Thus, it's said that `dill` can pickle a weakref.  So, I'd argue that it's not misleading, it's actually technically accurate.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I hear you and those are all true facts, I just think that's retroactively rationalizing metonymous usage as technically correct when really it's just as much precision-losing linguistic drift: sure, people have come to use "pickle" as a verb to mean the more general concept "serialize" - *because* a common and built-in serialization method is called "pickling" - but I don't think this is making things better for us, the actual benefit is tiny and in fact I suspect a lot of generalized usage of "pickle" is due to people who don't learn or value the distinction.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Imagine you came across a JavaScript developer saying "oh just JSON it" when they really mean "serialize it", or you get a bug report saying "I'm having a bug when I JSONify this object returned by your library" and then you spend time trying to figure out what they're talking about and why and JSON serialization works fine in all your testing and then it turns out they meant some other serialization. But I notice that `dill` itself uses "pickle" like this in its readme, and it seems `dill` is wire-compatible for all objects that `pickle` can handle, so I'll take back my -1.

Comment: (Or I would take back my -1, but I guess enough time has passed so now stackoverflow locked my vote in until any edit happens to the post. But let the record show I was willing.)

Comment: @mtraceur: no worries.  I'll clarify the language in the post a bit.

Answer (score 3):

I worked around this by switching between weak/strong reference in `__getstate__`/`__setstate__`:

```python
class DBObject(object):
    def __getstate__(self):
        s = self.__dict__.copy()
        s['_db'] = s['_db']()
        return s

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__ = state.copy()
        self.__dict__['_db'] = weakref.ref(self.__dict__['_db'])
```

Comment: the weak reference created in setstate will be a dead one, since the self.dict['_db'] in setstate is not existing anymore after exit the setstate scope, which means that the weak_reference() is returning None