# Unable to save kivy widgets to file

Tags: python, kivy, pickle, dill

Try as I might, I an unable to pickle kivy widgets using either pickle or dill. I've already viewed the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693929/saving-a-kivy-widget-to-a-file), but the answer given does not seem to work. I've attempted every protocol for both dill and pickle. Attempting this:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import pickle

widget=Widget()
pickle.dump(widget,open('example.pkl','wb'),protocol=4)
```

Gives an error like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nonsense.py", line 9, in <module>
pickle.dump(widget,open('test.pkl','wb'),protocol=4)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'weakref'>: attribute lookup weakref on builtins failed
```

Different protocols give different errors. I've attempted to use dill as well (since it can pickle a greater number of types) and I get a different set of errors, depending on the protocol used.

For protocol 0:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 0 positional arguments (1 given)
```

for protocol 4:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from __newobj_ex__ args has the wrong class
```

with variations on this theme for the protocols between the two.

Are widgets unable to be pickled in any way? Failing that, is it possible to save a widget to file in some other manner? It would be exceptionally difficult to save the information I need without being able to save any instance of the widget class as well.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by pickling a widget?

Comment: `dill` should be able pickle a weakref, so that will get past your original issue raised by `pickle`. What are the errors using `dill`. FYI, `dill` uses the `DEFAULT_PROTOCOL` which is typically either `2` or `3`, depending on your version of python.  But, I agree, it's unusual to pickle a widget.